# Continuity of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $ f:  \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $ ,  such that $f$ a convrex function:

$$ \forall _{ x,y \in \Bbb R} \forall _{ p,q >0}  
 p+q=1 :  f(px+qy) \le pf(x)+qf(y)  $$

Prove the continuity of a function $ f:  \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $

I can't solve . 
It's possible that I can use Lipschitz continuity.
I didn't have other ideas

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove first that:

If $a < s < t < u < b$ then $$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\le \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s}\le\frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}.$$

Now, use the above to prove Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Lemma, it was necessary to prove the continuity of one variable.
I know of this lemma and the proof of $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $
I do not see the analogy to many variables.